# Problem with compound assignment operators

Tags: python-3.x

Im stuck with this exercise, because if i wrote with shortcut operator the result is 1, therefor is 9

```
    a = 6
    b = 3
    a /= 2 * b
    print(a)
```

a = a / 2 * b   [result 9]
a /= 2 * b      [result 1]

BUT if i do this exercise with * and after / like this:

```
    a *= 2 / b
```

Why in this case they dont do (2/b) first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = a / 2 * b` is `a = 6 / 2 * 3` (following 'normal' math PEMDAS rules).

On the other hand,

`a /= 2 * b` is `a = 6 / (2 * 3)` (since the right hand side must be evaluated first, this essentially becomes `a /= 6` -> `a = a / 6`)

*why* the right-hand side must be evaluated first? because the statement `(a = 6 / 2) * 3` does not make sense.

**Regarding your edit**: The exact same behavior happens when comparing `a *= 2 / b` and `a = a * 2 / b`. The difference is that in this example `a` is 4 in both cases because both `(6 * 2) / 3` and 
`6 * (2 / 3)` evaluate to 4.

Comment: why the right hand side must be evaluated first? if i try with an expression with *= everything works great

Comment: @MC everything works great with `/=` too. It just so happens that `(6 * 2) * 3` is equal to `6 * (2 * 3)`

Comment: no i mean 6 * 2 / 3
anyway i read that the exponentiation operator uses right-sided binding. the other one left

Comment: @MC There are no exponentiation operators here, `*` is multiplication.

Comment: because of that i dont understand why i need to execute multiplication FIRST! ( in right-sided way)

Comment: @MC please read my answer again. If you don't understand it then explain exactly what is not clear.

Comment: so a = a / 2 * b and a /= 2 * b are 2 different expression?

Comment: ok now i get it, so simple. when i have /= it divide by every exression after the equal. I just thought only the first digit